# Invalid Chai property when testing smart contract

Tags: hardhat, mocha, chai, smock

In a [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) project I'm using [smock](https://smock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to mock an ERC20 contract and [chai's calledOnce](https://smock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fakes.html#called-once) to assert:

```
    const {expect} = require("chai")
    const {artifacts, ethers} = require("hardhat")
    const {smock} = require("@defi-wonderland/smock")

    it("Should successfuly invoke transfer of given ERC20", async () => {
        //ARRANGE
        const MyContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract")
        const myContract = await MyContractFactory.deploy()
        await myContract.deployed()

        const fakeERC20 = await smock.fake('IERC20');
        fakeERC20.transfer.returns(true)

        const erc20Contract = fakeERC20.address
        const amount = 5
        const to = '0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8'

        //ACT
        const txReceipt = await myContract.myTransfer(erc20Contract, to, amount)

        //ASSERT
        expect(fakeERC20.transfer).to.have.been.calledOnce
        expect(fakeERC20.transfer).to.have.been.calledWith(to, amount);
    })
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Invalid Chai property: calledOnce
```

I've tried using [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) and explained [here](https://stackify.dev/455239-invalid-chai-property-when-calling-calledonce) but got another error:

```
TypeError: { [Function]
  _watchable: 
   { callHistory: [ [Object] ],
     name: 'transfer',
     answerByIndex: {},
     answerByArgs: [],
     encoder: [Function],
     defaultAnswer: { value: true, shouldRevert: false } },
  atCall: [Function: bound atCall],
  getCall: [Function: bound getCall],
  returns: [Function: bound returns],
  returnsAtCall: [Function: bound returnsAtCall],
  reverts: [Function: bound reverts],
  revertsAtCall: [Function: bound revertsAtCall],
  whenCalledWith: [Function: bound whenCalledWith],
  reset: [Function: bound reset] } is not a spy or a call to a spy!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding

```
chai.use(smock.matchers)
```

So basically you should:

- Follow the official documentation of [smock](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock) (an awesome library!)
- If your tests are failing with `Invalid Chai property when calling calledOnce` you should install `sinon` and `sinon-chai`.
- Eventually your imports look more or less like:

  `const chai = require('chai')`

  `const sinon = require('sinon')`

  `const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai')`

  `const {ethers} = require('hardhat')`

  `const {smock} = require('@defi-wonderland/smock')`

  `const expect = chai.expect`

  `chai.use(smock.matchers)`

Answer (score 0):

From here [here](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/220#issuecomment-328989791).

You can resolve this issue by adding the below at the beginning of you test.
`chai.config.proxyExcludedKeys.push('calledOnce');`